# Match value of a list (select) in template

Tags: drupal, twig

I cant find a way to match the value of a select list.

I added a `list` type of field in a Drupal paragraph, with following values:

- light
- dark
- big.

I want to use those values to be able to apply different styles within one paragraph, this by selecting one of these values in the edit form.

```
 {% set paragraph_jumbotron = content.field_paragraph_jumbotron %}
  {% block content %}
    {% for item in paragraph_jumbotron['#items'] %}
      {% if item.entity.field_selector.value == 'big' %}
        <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
          ...
          </div>
        </div>
      {% elseif item.entity.field_selector.value == 'dark' %}
        <div class="h-100 p-5 text-white bg-dark rounded-3">
          ...
        </div>

      {% elseif item.entity.field_selector.value == 'light' %}
        <div class="h-100 p-5 text-white bg-dark rounded-3">
          ...
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: So what is not working? Are you sure you are applying the correct classes? As seen in your snippet you're applying `bg-light` when the value is `big` and `bg-dark` when the value is `light`

Comment: This is working. I find out the problem, it was because I've inverted the label and the raw value in he field settings, the label is capitalized: 
Dark|dark
Light|light
Big|big
So it did'nt work because i did'nt capitalize the value... Of course i've inverted the label and the raw value in the field settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is working. I find out the problem, it was because I've inverted the label and the raw value in he field settings, the system value was capitalized: Dark|dark Light|light Big|big So it did'nt work because i did'nt capitalize the value in the twig template... Thus i've inverted the label and the raw value in the field settings of the content.